# How do I make the SSH experience for one user the same as for another user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I've created a new Ubuntu Server. When I SSH in as root, I see:

```
root@server:
```

I created a user. When I SSH in as the new user, I see:

```
$
```

When I press the up arrow key as root, I see the last command I entered. When I press the up arrow key as the new user, I see:

```
$^[[A
```

Delete works as expected as root. As the new user, the delete key inserts:

```
^[[3~
```

LS provides color coded results for root, and no color for the new user. Other little vexations exist as well.

I assume there's a configuration file somewhere for root that's set all of these things. How can I apply these UI niceties to the new user I've created as well?

Comment: It sounds like you used some unusual tool for user account creation that did essentially no setup. The standard tool on Debian-derived systems is `adduser`, which should give you a fully-configured account and populated home directory.

Comment: Last I checked, Ubuntu doesn't link 'sh' to Bash anymore, they're using Dash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your new user does not have the same shell as your root user.

As root, open up `/etc/passwd`

Find your root user line. It will be near the top and look like this:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

The /bin/bash part is important.

Now find your new user. They likely have `/bin/sh` in the same place that root has `/bin/bash`.

Replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` and then log in again as your new user. That should solve it.

To make the default shell `/bin/bash` permanently for all user users, do this as root:

`useradd -D -s /bin/bash`

You can verify this has been set bytyping `useradd -D` and observing the value of the `SHELL= line`.

Comment: If you are editing the `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` files, use `vipw` to do so.  It does a syntax and consistency check before saving the file to help prevent you locking yourself out.  You can also change a user's shell with `usermod -s /path/to/new/shell username`

Comment: FYI, chsh is the preferred method to change shell.  Editing /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow should be discouraged as it can leave an account unable to login if it's not done properly.

Answer (score 5):

To ensure a similar user experience for everyone you have to perform two steps:

1. Skeleton/profile files

   - Edit or replace the shell skeleton files (/etc/skel) with the ones
     you want *new* users to get
   - Manually copy over the skeleton files for users you've already added. Make sure you chown the files to the user so that they can
     make changes for themselves!
   - Edit /etc/default/useradd to make sure every new user use the shell you want them to use
2. Altering the shell used by your current users. There are two methods:

   - The recommended one: `chsh -s /path/to/shell username`. Cat /etc/shells to see which one your system has
   - The also recommended one: `usermod -s /path/to/shell username`
   - The absolutely NOT recommended one: `vipw`. **You are editing the user database directly this way. Delete a character on the wrong place and you've locked yourself out. You're warned.**

A relevant tip regarding vipw - many people don't know how to use vi. Instead of learning it just for the use of vipw you can export a different editor in the enviroment before launching vipw. Example:

```
# export EDITOR=nano
# vipw
```

This will then launch the vipw wrapper via nano

Comment: Also note that you can change your default editor by editing the appropriate shell configuration file (Usually `.profile`, may be in `.bashrc` or other locations depending on your shell and how your OS sets up the skeleton files.)

Answer (score 0):

for useradd you dont want to do it everytime you create a new user you can do"

edit the /etc/default/useradd skeleton file (don't forget to make a backup though).

Edit the SHELL variable to be /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh.

Now every time you use useradd to add a new user bash is automatically their default shell.
"
If you want to change the shell of already existing users you have to edit the /etc/passwd file (please make sure to back have a backup of it).

Comment: for the color coded results

Comment: This does not do anything for new users that are created. They will still get /bin/sh if useradd -D -s /bin/bash is not used.

Comment: Unbuntu Server uses /etc/bash.bashrc for those customizations.

Comment: i am using arch linux so in my computer it is .bashrc sorry for the mistake